# Apply condition to multiple arrays

Tags: python, filter

How to apply a same condition to multiple arrays?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
b = np.array([2,3,4,5,6])
c = np.array([5,6,7,8,9])
a,b = a[c>6],b[c>6]
print (a,b)
```

Like this, I want to filter out elements in 'a' and 'b' using the same filter, then replace the original value. Although this code works fine, it will be very long if I want to apply this filter to many arrays.

Comment: you want to generalize this to any number of arrays?

Comment: something like `return (*(a[a>3] for a in args),)`

Comment: You changed your question. Do you want the last element, `c` in this case, always for checking  the condition?

Comment: @Bazingaa Yes, I want to use the same condition for `a` and `b`. `c` is just a example. You can consider the condition as any Boolean array which has the same length of  `a` or `b`.

Comment: Ok, my answer below uses the last argument, `c` in your question, for checking the condition and returns `a` and `b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `*args` to refer to all the arguments and return all resulting arrays at once. `for arg in args[:-1]` loops up to the second last argument (`b` in your case).

```
def check(*args):
    return [arg[args[-1]>6] for arg in args[:-1]] # args[-1] is c in your case
```

**Output**
You can access the elements of your returned list as the desired output.

```
[array([3, 4, 5]), array([4, 5, 6])]
```

Comment: Thanks! Although this function returns the right value, I need to assign the result to `a` and `b` again. This means that if I have many arrays, I need to write all of their names again. Can I replace their values in a shorter line?

Comment: Do you know the exact number of variables beforehand? I mean if you have a,b,c,d or just a,b or a,b,c,d,e etc etc.

Comment: Yes, I know the exact number n of variables beforehand. I want to apply the condition and save to these original variable again.